# UIImagePickerController Change Camera Source via delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to be able to change the UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice via a button. The Button I would like to use is placed in an overlay that is showing over the top of the ImagePicker when it runs.

I have an inkling that this will require me to use a delegate but my knowledge on delegates is very minimal. could someone point me in the right direction?

Here is the code I am using for my UIImagePickerController "GetPhoto" which checks if the device has a camera and enables the correct camera at start depending on which you have available, and if you have none it gives you camera roll.

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == takePictureButton) {
        overlayViewController *overlay = [[overlayViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]) {
                picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

            }
            else {
                picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
            }

            picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay; 
       }
       else {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        }
    }
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a view controller associated to the overlay, you can define a property for the image picker controller in the overlay view controller, probably `assign`ed rather than `retain`ed and define the actions of the button within the overlay view controller to affect the image picker controller instance referenced by that property.

Comment: Okay, so I have added an @property like this `@ property (nonatomic,assign) UIImagePickerController *picker;` and then a function like this `-(void)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Change Camera Now");
    
    picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
}` I don't know how this links to the mainViewController?

Comment: Soon after `overlayViewController *overlay = [[overlayViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];` do `overlay.picker = picker;`

Comment: Retain is perfectly fine. Assign is not. Assign can and will likely cause your app to crash when the image picker gets dealloc because the property will still point to the address of the nonexistent picker. If you must, use weak instead.

Comment: assign is used for non object oriented stuff like structs and typdefs. As Isaac says, use weak or strong. Please don't post ridiculous stuff like this.